# WPF XAML LINQ: How to load xml file only once?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq

I have a textbox, when its content changed, I want to query the xml file for elements that match the text in the textbox and display the result in a listbox.

My current code is:

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var xElem = XElement.Load("ProductTable.xml");
        ...
```

How should I code so that Load is called only once? As is, each time a keystroke is entered, the xml file is (re)loaded. Thanks.

Comment: You can create an instance variable, lazily loaded (or not). What more do you need?

Comment: Why not use `Autocomplete` textbox from WPF toolkit that makes suggestions as you type. It can also use XML datasource (any data source for that matter).... http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/auto-complete-box-in-wpf-toolkit/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `xElem` to be your class's field. Then in `TextChanged` handler check for `null`:

```
class MyControl : UserControl
{
   XDocument productTableDocument;

   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (productTableDocument == null)   
      {
         productTableDocument = XDocument.Load("ProductTable.xml");
      }
      // continue working with not null productTableDocument
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you might want to add tons of complexity, if your XML can become stale, if you need to load it asynchronously, if you need to reclaim memory at precise points, etc...

Comment: But this is the straightforward thing to do.